# prepared statement PDO Probably small mistake

Tags: php, pdo

im rewriting all my database queries so that they are prepared and with PDO (before I used mysqli) so that they are save against sql injections. Now I'm new to PDO so its probably a small mistake that I dont see, so I hope u guys can help me out because this code doesnt work.

```
 <?php

        function getUserBalance($steamid)
        {
            include 'settings.php';

            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host="$servername";dbname="$dbname"", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 



            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE steamid= :steamid");


            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->bind_param(":steamid", $steamid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute(); 



            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            { 
                return $row['balance'];
            } 

        }
         $stmt->close();


    ?>
```

Comment: Check this statement `new PDO("mysql:host="$servername";dbname="$dbname"",`Double quotes inside double quotes create problem

Comment: Plus you are mixing `mysqli with pdo` . `bind_param` is used in mysqli

Comment: @Saty hmm weird, i used this site http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php for an example and they are using it too?

Comment: It is `bindParam` not `bind_param` Both are different

Answer (score 1):

**Change this line**

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host="$servername";dbname="$dbname"", $username, $password);
```

**to this**

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Okey so now I changed it to new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);, moved the  $stmt->close(); within the function (oops) , and changed bind_param to bindParam, Thx guys its working now

```
<?php
    include 'ChromePhp.php';

    function getUserBalance($steamid)
    {
        include 'settings.php';
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 


        $sql = "SELECT balance FROM users WHERE steamid= :steamid";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 

        $stmt->bindParam(':steamid', $steamid, PDO::PARAM_STR); 

        $stmt->execute(); 



        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    { 
        return $row['balance'];
    } 
        $stmt->close();

    }


?>
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't connect in the every function but have to use the single already opened connection instead.  You may like the [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) I wrote.